# reindex and group dataframe using the repeated ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
        doc_id  term_candidate  tfidf
0   1240600489869402113 space           0.057618
1   1240600489869402113 capacity        0.057618
2   1240600489869402113 idea            0.057618
3   1340608455992815617 priority        0.064477
4   1340608455992815617 typical dates   0.064477
5   1340608455992815617 hope            0.064477
```

And I would like to group by the doc_id as follows:

```
doc_id  term_candidate  tfidf
1240600489869402113 space           0.057618
                    capacity        0.057618
                    idea            0.057618
1340608455992815617 priority        0.064477
                    typical dates   0.064477
                    hope            0.064477
```

I tried `groupby` but no luck, any ideas?

also to sort the tfidf values for each doc_id.

Comment: Do you mean `df.set_index(["doc_id", "term_candidate"])` ?

Comment: no, what i mean is similar to merge in excel i.e. to merge the doc_id across multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

If `df.set_index(["doc_id", "term_candidate"])` is not what you want you can try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["doc_id", "tfidf"])

mask = df.duplicated(subset="doc_id", keep="first")

df["doc_id"] = df["doc_id"].astype(str)
df.loc[mask, "doc_id"] = ""

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                doc_id term_candidate     tfidf
0  1240600489869402113          space  0.057618
1                            capacity  0.057618
2                                idea  0.057618
3  1340608455992815617       priority  0.064477
4                       typical dates  0.064477
5                                hope  0.064477
```